# Run Batch File from R

Tags: r, cmd

I've found a lot of answers on how to run R from a Batch file, but nothing about running a Batch File from R. I know one way to do this is to use `system`, `system2` or `shell`, but these methods wait for process in the Windows Command Prompt to finish before R accepts another input. I want to run a Batch File which calls a console application that runs indefinitely, and then allow R to do other things. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help page `?shell` says how to do it.    Just run

```
shell("MyScript.bat",   wait=FALSE)
```